# Which tenses can grammatically be combined in a single sentence or paragraph that refers to various time periods?

Tags: tenses

I am aware that there are many different tenses in the English language, but which tenses can be used in the same sentence without detracting from its coherence? For example, in a situation like this:

> Over and over again, I see their bodies, the way the monster and her father had left them after their horrifying last moments that the monster couldn't care enough to spare them from.

What tenses can be combined when speaking in the present about events that have not happened yet, may have happened, might happen, etc. in the same sentence or paragraph while still maintaining syntactical correctness?

Comment: Alas, one can only be aware of the past (_had, was/were, ate, washed_) and the present  (_has/have, am/is/are, eat/eats, wash/washes_) tenses in English. That's all the tenses there are in English. Both of these tenses can refer to past, present, or future time, in the right context.

Comment: @JohnLawler Is "tense" not the correct word to describe the present progressive, past progressive, imperfect, present perfect, etc. tenses? If it is not the correct word, which word would I use to specify that those are the tenses I am referring to?

Comment: In general there are no ***rules*** about which tenses are allowed to be combined in a sentence- I could probably construct a sentence containing all of them if I put my mind to it, although since there are so many it would have to be a mighty complicated sentence.

Comment: Some definitions of *tense* refer to the inflected forms of verbs, of which English has two present (e.g., *goes*) and preterite (*gone*).  More traditional definitions include combinations of auxiliaries and main verbs to give the traditional six -- present, past, future, present perfect, past perfect, and future perfect.  The relationship between tenses and the times they refer to is complex and non-obvious.  English also uses both inflection and auxiliaries to indicate verb aspects, e.g,. a progressive sense (with *-ing*: *are going*) and ability (*can go*).

Comment: If one allows periphrastic "tenses" like Past Perfect, then one has to allow **any** periphrastic construction to be a "tense", [like the "tenses" here](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/tense.html#tenselist). Clearly, that way lies madness. Or at least unneeded tension.